# android spinner if some item selected, other spinner gone

Tags: android, spinner

spinner a have 2 item : poison and non_poison

spinner b have 2 item : dart frog and viper

spinner c have 2 item : chicken and eggs

long story short, i want to make
"IF" selected item on spinner a = poison
"THEN" spinner b = visible, spinner c = gone

heres my code, tried using setOnItemSelectedListener, no error shown, but its not working the way it supposed to be, am i missing something in here ? please help me....

```
public class eatable extends Fragment {
public String spinner1x;

@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final FrameLayout mRelative = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.berita_layout, container, false);

    final TextView text1 = (TextView) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.text_test1);
    final TextView text2 = (TextView) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.text_test2);
    final TextView text3 = (TextView) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.text_test3);
    final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.spinner_test1);
    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.spinner_test2);
    final Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.spinner_test3);
    spinner1x = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> mRelative, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
            if (spinner1x.equals("poison")){
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }

    });
return mRelative;
}

}
```

Comment: Write the following  spinner1x = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(); in onItemSelected method

Comment: try to get text from spinner inside the onitemselected

Comment: put spinner1x inside onItemSelected method, still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to retrieve the currently **selected item** of your spinner & save it to your `spinner1x` string, & to implement the `onNothingSelected` method:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> mRelative, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
          spinner1x = mRelative.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
          // your code here
          if (spinner1x.equals("poison")){
              spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
});
```

> The **AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener** requires the `onItemSelected()`
>   and `onNothingSelected()` callback methods.

[Android Spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Comment: method getItemAtPosition(position) cannot resolve method,is this because my class extending fragment instead of activity ? if yes, what should i change that getItemAtPosition with ?

Comment: alright sir, its working nice and well, thank you very much, for confirmation, yes i forgot to retrived currently selected item

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> mRelative, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // Use spinner item position for this.
        if (position == 0){
            spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Default your 0th position already selected so that here spinner 3 not shown.For that you have to write else condition and in that you have to VISIBLE your spinner 3.

Answer (score 0):

I am just using your code with corrections..

```
public class eatable extends Fragment {
public String spinner1x;

    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final FrameLayout mRelative = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.berita_layout, container, false);

        final TextView text1 = (TextView) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.text_test1);
        final TextView text2 = (TextView) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.text_test2);
        final TextView text3 = (TextView) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.text_test3);
        final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.spinner_test1);
        final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.spinner_test2);
        final Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.spinner_test3);


        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> mRelative, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                // your code here
 spinner1x = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (spinner1x.equals("poison")){
                    spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }else {
                    spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    spinner3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
            }

        });
    return mRelative;
    }

    }
```